# Storing MySql result set in a varuable and passing it in a JQuery Switch statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am facing a problem in the code below. I am trying to catch the MySql query result set in a variable and use the same variable in the below mentioned JQuery code. Now the problem is that my array has more than 150 items. Can anyone please guide me how to catch the MySql Array in a variable and use the result set in below mentioned JQuery code.

```
  valueMatches : function(category, searchTerm, callback) {
          switch (category) {
          case 'account':
              callback([
                { value: '1-amanda', label: 'Amanda' },
                { value: '2-aron',   label: 'Aron' },
                { value: '3-eric',   label: 'Eric' },
                { value: '4-jeremy', label: 'Jeremy' },
                { value: '5-samuel', label: 'Samuel' },
                { value: '6-scott',  label: 'Scott' }
              ]);
              break;
            case 'filter':
              callback(['published', 'unpublished', 'draft']);
              break;
            case 'access':
              callback(['public', 'private', 'protected']);
              break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    var passedArray = <?echo json_encode($yourArray);?>;
</script>
```

this will result in a javascript array that is stored in the passedArray variable and that will be accessible in your js